# Alarm app in objective C sound

Tags: ios, nstimer, uilocalnotification

I am developing an app that will fire an alarm and play 5 secs of a song the user select, or the default sound every x time depending on the user input.. my problem is I do not know how to create this alarm, I have tried with `UILocalNotification`, but the problem is how I made the alarm sound again even if my application is on background?

here is what I've got so far:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSDate * secs = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:i*[secs doubleValue]];
notification.alertBody = @"Alarm";
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.fireDate = secs;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

but how could I make the notification and also, how to make the sound  play a user song even in background... I have also tried with `NSTimer` but it stops when the app is moved to background

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSTimer` when the app is in the foreground.

Look at the `repeatInterval` property of `UILocalNotification` for running in the background.

Comment: thanks but repeat interval i think it only works with NScalendarUnits and it will not work if I want to repeat the alarm every 5 minutes... and also how do I reproduce part of a song from de user library in de UIlocalnotification

Comment: Those are your options. You may need to schedule multiple notifications. Sounds need to be encoded properly for notifications so you may have issues with arbitrary sounds...